# Extending the matrixinput class

Tags: plugin-development, matrix

I'm trying to call the addBlock function from the Matrix fieldtype. Whenever a block is added i need to run some basic javascript. 
Does anyone have an idea how to go about this?
thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can listen to the add button's `click` event like so:

```
$('.matrix > .buttons > .add').on('click', function(e) {
    // your js
});
```